# Adding Content Files with F# NuGet package builder

Tags: f#, nuget, f#-fake

I'm trying to add just one dll to the output folder of any project that uses my NuGet package. I used F# to build it, and have run out of ideas on how to get it to work.

F# code for building:

```
NuGet (fun p ->
        {p with
            Authors = ["Delsys"]
            References = ["DelsysAPI.dll"]
            Project = projectName
            Description = projectDescription
            OutputPath = artifactsNuGetDir
            Summary = projectSummary
            WorkingDir = packagingDir
            Version = version
            Files = [(@"**/SiUSBXp.dll", Some @"lib", Some @"")]
            }) "DelsysAPI.nuspec"
```

The SiUSBXp dll is present in my NuGet package, but it isn't copied into the output folder when I include and build with this NuGet package. Any help or insights would be great.

Edit:

I've made some progress with this issue. I'm not sure if I should open a new thread, but basically the F# nuget creator thinks my project root folder is the C drive when I add that file as a Content File.

```
Running build failed.
Error:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\DelsysAPI\bin\Release'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at FSI_0005.Build-core.clo@45-2.Invoke(Unit _arg3) in C:\Users\path\to\project\DelsysAPI\trunk\build-core.fsx:line 52
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in D:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 626
```

Here's the new F# NuGet spec code:

```
    NuGet (fun p ->
        {p with
            Authors = ["Delsys"]
            References = ["DelsysAPI.dll"]
            Project = projectName
            Description = projectDescription
            OutputPath = artifactsNuGetDir
            Summary = projectSummary
            WorkingDir = packagingDir
            Version = version
            Files = [(@"SiUSBXp.dll", Some @"", Some @"")]
            }) ("DelsysAPI.nuspec")
```

I've tried using **SOURCE_DIRECTORY** but it thinks that value is C:/ProjectFolder as well.

Comment: It's been a while since I've had anything to do with that, but isn't that something that needs to be specified in the `.nuspec` file?

Comment: The F# code actually produces the nuspec file. I'll edit in what its output is.

Comment: "but it isn't copied into the output folder when I include and build with this NuGet package" - what does this mean? That it is not part of a package you trying to produce or is not copied into the bin when nuget dependency is used by some other project?

Comment: Hi Alex, the latter. For example, if this NuGet was included in the project MyWPF, and the project was built in Debug mode, I need this dll to be copied into the MyWPF/bin/Debug folder.

Comment: I think the path to SiUSBXp.dll must be relative to `WorkingDir`. Does `packagingDir` contain your dll? Edit: I see I am necro commenting. I'll leave the comment anyway.